# Prove whether a language is finite or infinite.

Tags: formal-languages, automata

Consider the language :

$L = \{w \mid w \in \{0, 1\}^∗, w \text{ has three times as many }1\text{'s as }0\text{’s}\}.$

Say whether $L$ is finite or infinite, and prove that you are correct.

I am assuming that the language described above is infinite. But, I am not sure how to set up the proof. What type of proof should I use? Contradiction, Inductive?
Any help or tips appreciated.

Comment: Can you try constructing infinitely many distinct words in the language?

Comment: Words would be w = a^3nb^n where a and b are 0/1. N is the number of 0's in the word, so wouldn't that be an infinite amount?

Comment: Show that $K=(0111)^*$ is infinite and is a subset of $L$.

Comment: Words of the form $w=1^{3n}0^{n}$ belong to $L$. There are other words in $L$ but it's enough to show that $1^{3n}0^{n}$ belong to $L$ and that the number of such words is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

A subset of your language is $\{ (0 1 1 1)^n \colon n \ge 0 \}$ (each zero is followed by three ones), and that one is infinite. Thus your language is infinite.